# Submit button in Salesforce1 visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile

Looking for a very basic example of how to get the submit button at the top

[image]

But seem only able to do this

[image]

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardController="User_Story__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">

     <script type='text/javascript' src='/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js'></script>
<script> 
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({name: "publisher.showPanel",
        onData:function(e) {
            Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name:"publisher.setValidForSubmit", payload:"true"});
    }});
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({ name: "publisher.post",
        onData: function(e) {
            alert("call some remote action here");
            Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name: "publisher.close",
                payload:{ refresh:"true" }});
    }}); 
</script>

    <button class="primaryButton cuf-publisherShareButton default uiBlock uiButton" accesskey="" 
            disabled="disabled" type="button" data-aura-rendered-by="5:1853.28">Submit</button>

</apex:page>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to add HTML elements to the container for your Visualforce page as it comes from a different server to your page, and the browser will block any attempt to access the DOM.  That, and the fact that the publisher only provides a hook to the submit button provided by Salesforce1, as opposed to allowing custom buttons to be created, suggests that what you are trying to do isn't possible at the moment.  There aren't any ideas for this either, so it might make sense to raise one.

Comment: Sorry Keir I completely missed your response.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for finally... The documentation is very poor, I don't normally moan.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js'></script>
<script> 
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({name: "publisher.showPanel",
        onData:function(e) {
            Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name:"publisher.setValidForSubmit", payload:"true"});
    }});
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({ name: "publisher.post",
        onData: function(e) {
            alert("call some remote action here");
            Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name: "publisher.close",
                payload:{ refresh:"true" }});
    }}); 
</script>
```